# Laravel select multiple values with radio button per user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I've created custom radio buttons that will select **Presence** section *Yes* or *No* depending on the user. But when I click the first user, the next user can't be clicked for the **Presence** section.

This is the view

[image: html presence table]

This is my view code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>
                <center>Presence</center>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php
        $i=1;
    @endphp
    @foreach ($employee as $employee)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="presence" value="Y" />
            <label for="radio1">
                <font color="#00B01D">
                <i class="fas fa-check"/> Yes</font>
            </label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="presence" value="N" />
            <label for="radio2">
                <font color="#FF0000">
                <i class="fas fa-times"/> No</font>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @php
        $i++;
    @endphp
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var presence = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({  
            url:"{{ url('http://localhost/admin/presence/add') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                presence:presence,
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()
            },
            success:function(result){
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my Controller function

```
public function addprespost(Request $request)
{
    $dataz = [
        'presence' => $request->input('presence'),
    ];
    DB::table('presence')->insert($dataz);
    return redirect('/admin/presence/add');
}
```

This is the table after data is inserted successfully

[image: database presence table]

Comment: How do you obtain the `id_user` to be inserted into the table?

Comment: Even if you want your submissions asynchronous, it is neither ideal nor neat submitting data that modifies your `presence` table using radio button clicks. Why not have an update or submit button instead, so that after all changes to the view you can then update the database table asynchronously.

Comment: To help you with a better answer, do you intend to update the user entry on the `presence` table or insert a new entry each time the radio botton is changed?

Comment: @UdoE. yep, I itend to update the user entry each time the radio button is changed

Answer (score 0):

For each presence row you generate you need to provide a unique name for the radio group. Currently the name is the same for every row so all the radio buttons are part of the same group.
Something like this should be enough:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="presence-{{$i}}" value="Y" />
<label for="radio1">
    <font color="#00B01D">
        <i class="fas fa-check"/> Yes</font>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="presence-{{$i}}" value="N" />
<label for="radio2">
    <font color="#FF0000">
        <i class="fas fa-times"/> No</font>
</label>
```

[Radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: yep, but how to pass it in my controller? do I  should put "foreach" ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper jQuery event listener for radio buttons and checkboxes is the `change` event listener. See the [jquery api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change). Specifically, this paragraph.

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements, boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and **radio buttons**, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

so you have to modify your script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){ 
        var presence = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url:"{{ url('http://localhost/admin/presence/add') }}", 
            method:"POST", 
            data:{ 
                presence:presence, 
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()
            }, 
            success:function(result){ } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

However, sending update data asynchronously to your database this way may not be beneficial performance-wise. see my comment on original post.